# HighCharts: Logarithmic Scale for Horizontal Bar Charts

Tags: javascript, scaling, highcharts, horizontal-scaling

I am working with [**HighCharts**](http://www.highcharts.com) to produce a bar chart. My values can range from as minimal as 0 to as high as 100k (example). Therefore, one bar of the graph can be very small and the other can be very long. HighCharts has introduced the feature of "Logarithmic Scaling". The example of which can be seen **[HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/ZUcCS/)**

My js code is written in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mangobug/TuKWT/) file. I want to display my horizontal axis (x-Axis) logarithmically. I have inserted the key **type** as shown in the example but the script goes into an infinite loop which has to be stopped.

What is the flaw in the execution or is logarithmic scaling for HighCharts still not mature?

**P.S** The commented line in jsfiddle is causing the issue

Comment: Your JS Fiddle run's just fine for me. Is the bug occurring only with live data?

Comment: Yea but check out the commented line in it **//type: 'logarithmic',**, uncomment and use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still experimental according to the [Official Documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#xAxis--type), so that might be the case:

"The type of axis. Can be one of "linear" or "datetime". In a datetime axis, the numbers are given in milliseconds, and tick marks are placed on appropriate values like full hours or days.

***As of 2.1.6, "logarithmic" is added as an experimental feature, but it is not yet fully implemented. Defaults to "linear".***

Try it: "linear", "datetime" with regular intervals, "datetime" with irregular intervals, experimental "logarithmic" axis."

Comment: yea i read that but still in their roadmap it is in fall-2011. Though I would agree and let it be done !!!

Comment: I would suggest trying Google Charts API as I myself shifted from all these bloated APIs like HighCharts and some others to Google's and am pretty happy. It's rock stable!

Answer (score 10):

Since the "official" method is still buggy, you can achieve the log scale more manually by manipulating your input data with a base 10 log and masking your output data raising 10 to the output value. See it in action here http://jsfiddle.net/7J6sc/ code below.

```
function log10(n) {
 return Math.log(n)/Math.log(10);   
}

chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar',
        marginRight: 200,
        marginLeft: 10,
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Negative'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [''],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: '',
            align: 'high',
        },
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
             return Math.round(Math.pow(10,this.value));
            }
        }
    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        x: -50,
        y: 100,
        floating: true,
        borderWidth: 1,
        shadow: true
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '' + this.series.name + ': ' + Math.round(Math.pow(10,this.y)) + ' millions';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                formatter: function() {
                   return Math.round(Math.pow(10,this.y)); 
                }
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        "data": [log10(4396)],
        "name": "A"},
    {
        "data": [log10(4940)],
        "name": "B"},
    {
        "data": [log10(4440)],
        "name": "C"},
    {
        "data": [log10(2700)],
        "name": "D"},
    {
        "data": [log10(2400)],
        "name": "E"},
    {
        "data": [log10(6000)],
        "name": "F"},
    {
        "data": [log10(3000)],
        "name": "G"},
    {
        "data": [log10(15000)],
        "name": "E"}],

});
```

Comment: seems like a pretty workable solution, though any draw-backs?

Comment: The biggest draw-back is you can't define your axis ticks to be non-linear. This prevents you from using tick intervals more granular than powers of 10 without them seeming odd. eg tick's at 1, 3.16, 10, 31.6, 100, 316

Comment: Tried this and it worked like a charm. It should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

For those of you who are still looking for an answer :

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/TuKWT/76/

Or SO snippet :

```js
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        defaultSeriesType: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Negative'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H'],
        title: {
            text: null
        }
    },
    yAxis: {
        type: 'logarithmic',
        //min: 0, <= THIS WILL CAUSE ISSUE 
        title: {
            text: null,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return this.x + ':' + this.y + ' millions';
        }
    },
    plotOptions: {
        bar: {
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    series: [{
        "data": [4396,4940,4440,2700,2400,6000,3000,15000],
        }],

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>
```