# Why does this highchart plot not render in IE or chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

You can see the plot in this jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/essennsee/y5HCm/

It renders fine in Firefox but only displays the legend in IE and Chrome.

If I remove the following it works so is there an alternative way to format the labels?:

```
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return '1e'+Math.log10(this.value);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Because `Math.log10` is [only available in Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log10)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001022/highcharts-logarithmic-scale-for-horizontal-bar-charts) that discusses a bug in this implementation of highchart  - I updated your fiddle with this code:

```
labels: {
    formatter: function() {
        return '1e'+ Math.round(Math.pow(10,this.value));
    }
}
```

From what I understand, if you round numbers up they work and it started working.

Comment: The problem's not really with the rounding, just the fact that only Firefox has support for `Math.log10`. Consequently, every other browser (at least Safari) fails with an undefined function error.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it by using toExponential. Updated version can be seen in the jsfiddle. I wasn't aware Math.log10 is not supported in other browsers.