# Highcharts / Bar Chart - How to display a bar for every non-zero / positive value?

Tags: highcharts

I'm using a Highcharts Bar chart similar to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L29f7nrr/).

What:
I would like to display a very small bar for low positive values that would otherwise be hidden on the chart. Are there a configuration options that support this?

Why:
In my use case, the distinction between 0 and low positive values is important to the user. The default chart behavior scales bar heights in relation to one other. For this reason, charting a highly varied data set (e.g. a mix of very low and high values) will display no bar for both zero and low positive values.

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
          type: 'column',
          marginLeft: 0,
          marginRight: 0,
          marginBottom: 25,
          marginTop: 0
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            grouping: true,
            // pointPadding: 0.1,
            // groupPadding: 0.2,
            // pointPlacement: 'on',
            states: {
              hover: {
                // Prevent color change on hover
                brightness: 0
              }
            }
          },
          column: {
            borderWidth: 0
          },
          bar: {
            minPointLength: 10
          }
        },
        xAxis: {
          labels: {
            enabled: true,
            y:0,
            style: {
              color: '#ccc',
              fontSize: '14px'
            }
          },
          tickWidth: 15,
          minPadding: 0,
          maxPadding: 0,
          startOnTick: true
        },
        yAxis: {
          min: 0,
          gridLineColor: '#ddd',
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          labels: {
            enabled: true,
            x: 0,
            style: {
              color: '#ccc',
              fontSize: '14px'
            }
          }
        },
        series: [{
            data: [0, 1, 0, 2, 3, 5, 8, 5, 15, 14, 25, 300]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9001022/highcharts-logarithmic-scale-for-horizontal-bar-charts ?

Comment: How about using combination `null` points instead of 0 and `minPointLength` ? Take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/L29f7nrr/2/

Comment: I second @PawełFus suggestion. A logarithmic axis is not a logical solution.

Comment: Thanks folks. I'll give @PawełFus solution a shot.